# How do I use \tcbline

Tags: tcolorbox

Why am I not able to correctly use the `\tbcline` feature of the `tcolorbox` package (see [Pg.198 of the documentation available on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf)) ?

My trial on Overleaf can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/4843764xnxzdt#/14857418/).

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not provide external links, it's just tedious to get the code from somewhere else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tcbline` feature needs the `skins` library, i.e. either say

```
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
```

or

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
```

This example works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \tcbset{enhanced,colframe=blue!50!black,colback=white}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[title=tcbline example]
        This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
        \tcbline
        Here, you have the middle part of the box.
        \tcbline
        And here is the lower part of the box.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent package and great response!

Comment: @champost: Thanks (the package is great, but it's not by me (:-() You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Oops...sorry about that. Thanks Thomas. F. Sturm and TeX SO community!